# How is the Daybreak mental state transferred from person to person?

Tags: plot-device, daybreak

In John Barnes' [Daybreak series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?28030), we are given to understand that people are infected with "Daybreak" -- ideas that lead them to create bioengineered bacteria, immense fusion bombs, and other means of destroying civilization, while neglecting their own health and safety. Rather like smart, dedicated zombies. At one point an infected man talks to another and concludes by saying, "And that's how it's transmitted," or words to that effect, and the other becomes infected. Well, I am perplexed. How, in the Daybreak world, are people infected with this peculiarly dangerous mental state?

Comment: Oh no!  Barnes has just infected all his readers?!

Comment: Barnes seems to treat human minds as being generic information processors, and Daybreak propagates like a computer virus. So it is transmitted simply by communication, especially speech.

Comment: A meme machine, eh?